# Fedora 15 i686 report only 2.6 GB RAM

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, pae, x86

I have laptop Asus N53SV with 4 GB of RAM, i7 with integrated card and dedicated GPU.  My problem on Fedora is that system reports only 2.6 GB RAM. I know that I should use kernel with PAE but even after I install it, I have only 2.6 GB RAM avaiable. Now I use 3.0.0 rc6 kernel, but still nothing. Is it possible that the integrated GPU uses almost 1GB of RAM ? Can I check it somehow?

```
$ free
Non-standard uts for running kernel:
release 3.0-0.rc6.git6.1.fc15.i686=3.0.0 gives version code 196608
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2752180    2527816     224364          0      11232     499444
-/+ buffers/cache:    2017140     735040
Swap:      4849660     500048    4349612
```

dmidecode
http://pastebin.com/CNrph9KA
kernel logs
http://pastebin.com/QvqUmEZb

Comment: See [this related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15256) about the non-PAE case. With a PAE kernel, what tool reported 2.6GB? Post the output of `free`. Also post the kernel logs from around boot time (in `/var/log/kern.log`, I think), especially [the ones I cite in my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15266#15266). The output of `dmidecode` (very long, use http://pastebin.com/ or similar) might have relevant information.

Comment: I checked it with free and in System Monitor. Both of this tools shows ~2.6 GB.

Comment: That log is from a non-PAE kernel, and as far as I understand this is as much as you can get from a non-PAE kernel on your hardware. There's ~1.3GB of RAM that the kernel can't map because it's above the 4GB address map (last `BIOS-e820:` line). With a PAE kernel this part should be in use; please post the logs when you boot a PAE kernel.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible that the integrated GPU uses almost 1GB of RAM?

Easily.  Many integrated GPUs do not have their own dedicated memory, instead using a portion of the system memory carved out by the BIOS.

> Can I check it somehow?

Probably.  Check the BIOS settings, and/or the system manual.  You should be able to control the memory allocation from there.  (If you can't find your copy of the manual, [you can find a PDF version on Asus' site for the machine, on the Downloads tab](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Multimedia_Entertainment/N53SV/).)

Answer (score -2):

Is it 64 bit or not? I believe the cutoff point is around 3.25gB that a 32 bit OS can handle, so it wouldn't fully utilize it due to addressing issues.

Comment: That's true for the non-PAE case, but a PAE-aware kernel should handle up to 64GB.